Upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 fails
Repeated attempts at upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 fail with this error message:
Error marking the upgrade (E:Internal Error, pkgProblemResolver::ResolveByKeep is looping on package python3-pyqt5:amd64.)This usually means installed packages have unmet dependencies.

Unfortunately, I have no clue what to do at this point.

Please don't upgrade. The upgrade path has serious bugs. Fresh install 24.04 instead

I gave up, tried a fresh install--and even that turned out to be wonky, Apparently it didn't clear all remnants of 22.04 when formatting. Now the new install 24.04 LTS won't update. It's becoming clear this dist version may not be ready for prime time.

You can try running these commands and see if they fix your issue:
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

